# extension - site interaction (SoundCloud track progress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, soundcloud

I want to be able to alter a SoundCloud video's progress from within the extension.

Possibilities I've been thinking of:

- *HTMLMediaElement* interface

On YouTube there is a `<video>` element, which handles HTMLMediaElement interface interaction. On SC, there is no such element (i.e. `<audio>` or `<video>`), so invoking something like `$('audio').currentTime = 100` is impossible. On the other hand, SC uses *HTMLMediaElement* in JS, where it seems to create an Audio object and invokes appropriate *HTMLMediaElement* functions on it. Keep in mind Chrome extensions cannot invoke page's scripts.

- Click emulation

Emulating a click on any given part of the progress bar, so the video jumps to the right location. It would require specifying appropriate x,y coords. Is it possible at all?

Please share your thoughts. Is any of the options above possible?

Comment: An example page link would be helpful, otherwise it's not entirely clear why you mention `video progress` and then talk about `audio`. And what do you mean by altering the progress - is it seeking only or something else as well?

Comment: my apologies, all <tags> were not displayed, it should be more clear now

Comment: does it make any sense now? or I should make some clarifications?